# How are such sets of natural numbers called?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, terminology, diophantine-equations

I heard about this problem an year ago, but I just can't remember the name.
The problem goes like this: study the sets

> $\{a_1,a_2,\dotsc,a_m\}\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that if $1\leq i<j\leq m$, then $a_i a_j+1$ is a perfect square.

Is there a technical term for such sets?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sets of $m$ integers with this property are called *integer Diophantine $m$-tuples*. A good starting point to learn about them (and about *rational* Diophantine $m$-tuples) is [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.00569.pdf) by 
Dujella, Kazalicki, Mikic, and Szikszai.

Comment: Andrej Dujella maintains a (quite complete!) list of references on these,   https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/dtuples.html and has a recent survey paper, "What is ... a diophantine m-tuple", in the AMS Notices http://www.ams.org/publications/journals/notices/201607/rnoti-p772.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you about some special cases.

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&ab+T=x^2\\&ac+T=y^2\\&bc+T=z^2\end{aligned}\right.$$

We need to find solutions $a,b,c$ - that was an arithmetic progression.  This will help the solution of the equation Pell.

$$p^2-3s^2=T$$

Knowing any solution of the equation Pell $(p_0;s_0)$ you can always find the following formula.

$$p_1=2p_0+3s_0$$

$$s_1=p_0+2s_0$$

Having any decision - can immediately write down the solution of this system.

$$a=2s-p$$

$$b=2s$$

$$c=2s+p$$

$$x=s-p$$

$$y=s$$

$$z=s+p$$

Interesting here is that the $x,y,z$ looks like an arithmetic progression.

I thought as this task to generalize and use for any numbers.  It turned out that you can do without calculations.  For the system of equations:

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&ab+T=x^2\\&ac+T=y^2\\&bc+T=z^2\end{aligned}\right.$$

Enough to factor the following number:

$$bc=(y+c)^2-T$$

Using these numbers you can easily write the solution of this system of equations.

$$a=b-c-2y$$

$$b=b$$

$$c=c$$

$$x=b-c-y$$

$$y=y$$

$$z=y+c$$

It is better to use a more General approach. We write the system.

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&xy+T=a^2\\&xz+T=b^2\\&xq+T=c^2\\&yz+T=d^2\\&yq+T=k^2\\&zq+T=n^2\end{aligned}\right.$$

If the number $T$, lay at the multipliers. We find then the desired settings.

$$T=3(p-t-s)(p+t-s)(p+s)^2$$

Then the solution can be written as.

$$x=t^2+2s^2+2ps-p^2$$

$$y=t^2-s^2+2ps+2p^2$$

$$z=4t^2-(p-s)^2$$

$$q=3(p+s)^2$$

$$a=p^2+ps+s^2-t^2$$

$$b=2t^2+s^2+ps-2p^2$$

$$c=3(p+s)s$$

$$d=2t^2-2s^2+ps+p^2$$

$$k=3(p+s)p$$

$$n=3(p+s)t$$

Comment: This doesn't engage with the question, at all.